# C# (Xamarin): looping through XML

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin

I have a Xamarin (C#) project, where I am trying to loop through some XML, but for some reason my code is not working.

This is what I have now:

```
DeviceList = new List<DeviceInfo>();
        string ResultStatus = "";
        string ResultDevice = "";
        var result = Encoding.Default.GetString(e.Result);

        result = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" + result;

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(result);

        string xPathStatus = "ed_listdevices";
        var nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(xPathStatus);
        foreach (XmlNode xNode in nodes) {
            ResultStatus = xNode.SelectSingleNode("//status").InnerText;
            ResultDevice = xNode.SelectSingleNode("//device").InnerText;
        }

        if (ResultStatus.ToLower() == "ok") {
            XmlDocument deviceDoc = new XmlDocument();
            deviceDoc.LoadXml(result);
            var deviceNodes = deviceDoc.SelectNodes(xPathStatus + "/device");
            //foreach(XmlNode dNode in deviceNodes) {
            for (int i = 0; i < deviceNodes.Count; i++) {
                DeviceList.Add(new DeviceInfo() {
                    DeviceID = deviceNodes[i].SelectSingleNode("//id").InnerXml,
                    DeviceName = deviceNodes[i].SelectSingleNode("//name").InnerXml,
                    DeviceExtraName = "",
                    DeviceOnlineStatus = deviceNodes[i].SelectSingleNode("//status").InnerXml,
                    Location = deviceNodes[i].SelectSingleNode("//address").InnerXml,
                    Time = deviceNodes[i].SelectSingleNode("//time").InnerXml
                });
            }
```

}

When I step though the code I get the "ResultStatus" and "ResultDevice" correctly, and when I get to the
 `for (int i = 0; i < deviceNodes.Count; i++)`
the "deviceNodes" variable have a count of 91, and I can see all the individual xml elements that I am suppose to get from the webservice I am calling.

However, when I loop through deviceNodes[i] I only get values from the very first XML  element (yes, the value of "i" does change). In other words, my DeviceList is filled with 91 entries with the same values.

Am I missing something obvious?? What am I doing wrong since this isn't working??

PS: I have also tried using a `foreach (XmlNode node in deviceNodes)` but the result was the same.

Comment: How big is your xml? When size of the file is small (we are mostly doing it with size up to few megabytes), it is almost always easier to put together classes that adhere to your schema and deserialize xml to POCO and work with them.

Comment: I believe using "//" syntax in your selector tells it to search from the root, not from the local node

Comment: Is  DeviceInfo() declared as STATIC?

Comment: @Jason You got it :-)  Removing the "//" did the trick! If you put that in an answer, I will accept it as the correct answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"//" in the selector tells it to search from the root node of the document.  If you want to search locally under the "current" node, remove the "//"